# Can Spotlight indexes be copied to other Macs?

Tags: smb, spotlight

We have recently switched to SMB protocol and now have 12TB of external storage that needs to be reindexed. The amount of network traffic caused such a slowdown that I had to disable indexing on over half of the Macs. Is there a way to copy a Spotlight db from one of the Macs that has completed indexing to another Mac?